# Old Product Icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I hate the new product icons (chevron instead of triangles for expanded folders)[image]

I've browsed through the settings but have been unable to change back to the old style. Anyone know how?

Comment: according to the release notes they have spend a long time to redesign the icons. I don't know why they needed redesign, they where very clear and looked great. I don't like the Debug side bar icon.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61582967/836330 - the icons will be changeable via an icon theme soon.