# VS Code: Folding code with [+] [-] sign instead of the default [>] [∨]

Tags: visual-studio-code

Summary: I want 2 things:

- ***(1)***  I want my folding symbols in VS Code to be **[+][-]** (similar to Visual Studio) instead of the default **[>][v]** one
- ***(2)***  I want my **Extensions** section can have **downloads and rating** preview

Story: I randomly saw those features ***(1)*** on [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396809/9787887) on Stackoverflow and ***(2)*** in [the site Extension Gallery of VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery). I don't have enough reputation to comment below [the Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396809/9787887) to ask him how to get those ***(1)*** [+][-] symbol features. I tried to put [a question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69212/vs-code-settings) on Software Recommendation Stack Exchange but didn't get an answer.

**[The question I put on Softwarerecs site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69212/vs-code-settings) is more detailed** with images so you guys can visit it to see the images and more detailed question.

First time I asked, thank you in advance.

**Edit:**
***(1):*** It seems the [+][-] icons were replaced with [>][v] recently. I don't know if there's a workaround to get it back? I think [this discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78024) will be a bit helpful to this problem.

***(2) solved:*** Because I resized the sidebar window to too small so the *downloads and rating* part didn't show up. As I expand the sidebar bigger the *downloads and rating* shows up again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43476212/ maybe this can help

Comment: Hmm can I ask what version of visual studio code you use?

Comment: @Saharsh That question you posted says **It only shows them if you hover over the gutter**. My case it doesn't show the [+] and [-] icons at all. And what I want is to show the [+][-], not "to show the folding icon when not hovering" (because even when hovering they ([+][-]) don't show up anyway)

Comment: @Francisaskquestion
I type `code -v` and what I get is: `1.38.1  b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0  x64`. Does it mean my version is 1.38.1?

Comment: @HuỳnhLợiNguyễn I don't personally use VS code but (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2948#issuecomment-183540068) this github issue led me there. Although this issue was where your requirement was introduced and not actually put to use.

Comment: yes it is. Can you show a image of your extensions tab? It should have a downloads and rating in default

Comment: @Francisaskquestion Oh shit. Yes It's defaulted. Because I resized the sidebar window to too small so the downloads and rating didn't show up. I'll mark (2) solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add custom folding controls icons with the help of this extension: [Minimalist Product Icon Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ElAnandKumar.el-vsc-product-icon-theme)

its override the product icons that ship with VS Code, Activity bar icons, Status Bar, Code collapse/expand

Answer (score 3):

In the first problem, I can confirm that in the latest version of VSCode the [+] and [-] was no longer used. And what I searched about [basic editing of folding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding), changing the icons was not included. Also the thread you mentioned was back from 2016 and many changes was made to VSCode UI. So I think it is not possible to simple make the folding icon [+] and [-].

If you want to read more about the update logs of VSCode follow this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_38).

Comment: Oh I can't believe that it used to be the [+][-] and be replaced with the confused [>][v] recently :((
There're [better proposed design](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2948#issuecomment-183540068), why did they just choose the [>][v]

Comment: you can change the svg icons used, but you need to overwrite them at every VSC update. You can find the previous +/- icons at github.

Comment: @rioV8 about the svg icons you mentioned. Can you please tell me where did you find it?
I'm having a problem locating the svg of the collapsed and expand for the code

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to change the code folding icons with via a theme in vscode v1.45.  From
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#product-icon-themes

> #### Product icon themes
>
> Visual Studio Code contains a set of built-in icons that are used in
>   views and the editor, but can also be used in hovers, the status bar,
>   and by extensions. These icons are **product icons** as opposed to
>   **file icons**, which are used next to file names throughout the UI.
>
> The product icons that ship with VS Code are contained in the [Codicon
>   icon font](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-codicons) and form the
>   **default** product icon theme. Extensions can provide new product icon themes to redefine these icons and give VS Code a new appearance.
>
> See the [Product Icon
>   Themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/product-icon-theme)
>   documentation for more details and there is a [Product Color
>   Theme
>   Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/product-icon-theme-sample)

I'm pretty **sure** someone will make a theme soon that includes the folding icons you prefer.  The ones involved that should be changed:

```
.codicon-fold-down:before { content: "\eaf3" }
.codicon-fold-up:before { content: "\eaf4" }
.codicon-fold:before { content: "\eaf5" }
.codicon-folder-active:before { content: "\eaf6" }
.codicon-folder-opened:before { content: "\eaf7" }
```

Possibly using these:

```
content:"\ea5e";  // plus

content:"\ea33";  // minus
```

or similar.